# Plot frequencies only on certain condition

Tags: r, statistics

I have two columns in my csv sheet:

`G_Art` which can have the values `K` or `V` or `Date` which includes certain dates.

I want to have all dates where the the value is `K` and plot them into a frequency table.

This is how my data looks like:

```
> (dput(head(data$date,10)))
c("21.08.2013", "20.08.2013", "20.08.2013", "20.08.2013", "19.08.2013", 
"19.08.2013", "19.08.2013", "19.08.2013", "16.08.2013", "16.08.2013"
)
> (dput(head(data$G_ART,10)))
c("V", "V", "K", "K", "V", "V", "V", "V", "K", "V")
```

I know that I can match the `K` value with:

```
grep("K", data$G_ART)
```

However how to match this with the dates?

**UPDATE**

When putting this into the `hist` function I get:

```
> hist(data$date[grep("K", data$G_ART)], freq=TRUE, main="Transaction Types")
Error in hist.default(data$date[grep("K", data$G_ART)], freq = TRUE,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? `data$date[grep("K", data$G_ART)]`

Comment: Thx for your answer! However putting this into the `hist` function I get: `> hist(data$date[grep("K", data$G_ART)], freq=TRUE, main="Transaction Types")
Error in hist.default(data$date[grep("K", data$G_ART)], freq = TRUE,  : 
  'x' must be numeric`

Comment: You will probably need to do something like this `hist(as.Date(dataevector,'%d.%m.%Y'), 'weeks')`. Look up the help entry on `hist`.